# how to select elements from do-loop for some condition?

Tags: condition

This is my original coding:

```
Do[Print[Det[Table[(-0.15 + 0.001*x)^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]], {x, 1, 10}]
```

I want to select `{x}` that

```
Det[Table[(-0.15 + 0.001*x)^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]
```

is positive value

how to program this problem?
`Select[]` can't do this

Comment: Using exact arithmetic, all determinants are exactly zero.

    res = Table[{x, Det[Table[(-15/100 + x/1000)^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]}, {x, 1, 10}]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Table` instead of `Do`, in this way you keep the complete result (including x-value):

```
res = Table[{x,Det[Table[(-0.15 + 0.001*x)^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]}, {x,1, 10}]  
Select[res,#[[2]]>0&]
(*{{3, 6.89637*10^-201}, {4, 6.10433*10^-201}, {5, 2.15982*10^-203}, {9,2.99791*10^-202}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list = {};(*empty list*)
Do[AppendTo[list, Det[Table[(-0.15 + 0.001*x)^(i + j), {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}]]], {x, 1,10}]
Select[list, # > 0 &]
(*{6.89637*10^-201, 6.10433*10^-201, 2.15982*10^-203, 2.99791*10^-202}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the support.